# creating an array in JavaScript on given format

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, gcal

how can I create an array in the format below:

---

```
  var options =
                 [
                    {
                        title: 'Laziness',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Dizziness,Sleepiness',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Click for Google',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                        url: 'http://google.com/'
                    }
                ];
```

---

I've tried like that:

---

```
for(var i in data)
           {
             options = {
                    title:data[i].eventNames,
                   start:data[i].eventDates
               };
            }
```

---

but it doesn't display in correct format, how can I implement this

Comment: Maybe I don't get the question well, but What is wrong with the first example ?

Comment: what's in your initial 'data' variable?

Comment: @Bartdude : its using gcal calendar need correct format otherwise wont work ,eventNames and eventDates are two arrays passing from post success .using this i need to create the array

Comment: @EyalBarta 

{"status":"success","data":{"eventNames":["test1","test2","test3"],"eventDates":["2014\/05\/30","2014\/05\/23","2014\/05\/29"]}}

Comment: you have your answer below.. options should be an Array, then use the push() method

Comment: Indentation levels gone wild. Please, fix them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Like This

> Javascript

```
var arr = [];
var len = 5; //Replace Ur data With Len, Take Data Length or count for loop
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {    
    arr.push({
        key: 1 + i,
        value : 1 + i + "Hi"
    });
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/Lb3yW/37/)

Answer (score -1):

You can create options before loop, and then in loop push objects:

```
options = [];
for(var i in data)
           {
             options.push( {
                    title:data[i].eventNames,
                   start:data[i].eventDates
               })
            }
```

Comment: hhh same answer, same time.. I'll delete mine

Comment: Now am getting results like this

title:["test1", "test2", "test3"]

but i need it like


 
                    {
                        title: 'test1',
                       
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'test2'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'test3',
                       
                    }
                ]

Comment: My result is : [ { title: 'test1', start: 'test2' } ] when i push it to array. Don't know why You have different result. I'm pretty sure it is Ok.